# is wagtail version 2.1 support python 2.7?

Tags: python, wagtail

I have this error message.

```
This version of Wagtail requires Python 3.4 or above - you are running 2.7
```

When i tried to create a new wagtail project.

```
wagtail start project name
```

I installed:

- Python 2.7
- Wagtail last version (2.1)

Is latest wagtail version (2.1) not supported by python 2.7 or there is another problem?

### Update:

When i try to create it without activate virtual environment. it is done. so is there problem in virtual environment?

Comment: Doesn't the error message you posted answer your question? Wagtail 2.1 supports Python 3.4+, so no, it doesn't work for Python 2.7.

Comment: i created it. but without virtual environment.so it is supported by python 2.7.and the problem is in virtual environment

Answer (score 5):

The error message answers your question. Wagtail 2.1 requires Python 3.4 or above.

You need to install Python 3.4 or above and try again. Note you might use virtualenv to install packages per project. Eg:

```
$ virtualenv env -p python3
$ source env/bin/activate
$ pip install wagtail
$ env/bin/wagtail start projectname
```

Comment: i created it with python 2.7. but without activate virtual environment.so it is supported by python 2.7.and the problem is in virtual environment

Comment: The fact that Python code runs, isn't the same as 'it is supported'. Python2 and Python3 have more in common than they differ. You bumped into an explicit error telling you you did it wrong. Is it that hard to understand? It is also in the documentation: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/releases/2.0.html?highlight=python2#upgrade-considerations. You have been told many time: Make sure you use Python3 and carry on! Try `which python` and `which wagtail` to make sure that you use the right ones. I can't see what you installed globally. But I'm sure using a p3 env solves your issue.